# Drawing in the "margin" as an IDE/editor feature

Tags: c++, ide, drawing

I have a modest codebase (C++) that is well-documented but nonetheless very complex. I am involved in its maintenance and debugging, and I find myself drawing the same pictures over and over again, to check for wayward pointers and to look for optimizations. The pictures help a lot, as inconsistencies have crept into the code from time to time on seemingly logical optimizations.

It may be too much to ask, but is there an editor that would let me draw in the margins, a la MS Paint, as auxiliary comments, and maybe even to tack the picture to a particular line? Just in case such a thing exists, I would ideally like to use it alongside Vim.

Comment: How about a comment with a link to a web-page with a photo of your scribbles?

Answer (score 1):

Such an editor would have suffered the kind of feature creep that is against the philosophy of vim (or at least vi).  You're more likely to be happy with adding your own layer of indirection between vim and an external doodling app.  As @Mats Petersson suggests, a URL is one way.  Or a filename relative to some directory, or an XML tag.

A plugin for vim that recognizes your layer might automatically display your doodles.  If Clippy can be implemented as a vim plugin, surely so can this.

If ascii-art suffices, try the plugin DrawIt, http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=40 ;  or use that webpage's search box.